# DNS request to find domain of IP address

Tags: dns

Suppose that there are some hosts and one server in the same network that has DNS server running. Also suppose that there is no knowledge of what domain name (or hostname, you can say) is.

By using only IP address, is there any way I can use to figure out what domain name hosts use?

Answer (score 2):

ping -a 192.168.1.3

will return the hostname, as well as the ping results

nslookup 192.168.1.3

will return the nameserver the IP is using and the hostname

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could `nslookup` your own IP address.  If this is a Windows system, `ipconfig` also gives you this information.